Timer Increments By One Whenever User Tries To Reset It Back To Zero In Android
I made a standard stopwatch app in Android Studio using jetpack compose. It gives the user the ability to reset the stopwatch back to zero, however there is a problem. The stopwatch will reset back to zero but then immediately increment by one.
Here is the code.
There is a variable to hold the time called "time". There is a variable to determine if the timer is running called "isTimerRunning". There is a function that starts the timer using a while loop inside of a coroutine scope called "startTimer". There is a function the stops the timer and resets it back to zero called "resetTimer". There is a Text composable that displays the time. There are two buttons, one starts the timer, the other resets it.
// Time Variable
var time by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

// Is Timer Running Variable
var isTimerRunning by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

// Start Timer Function
fun startTimer() {
    isTimerRunning = true
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        while (isTimerRunning) {
            delay(1000)
            time += 1
        }
    }
}

// Reset Timer Function
fun resetTimer() {
        isTimerRunning = false
        time = 0
    }

// App Layout
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
) {
    // Display Timer
    Text(text = time.toString())

    // Start Timer Button
    Button(onClick = { startTimer() }) {
        Text(text = "Start")
    }

    // Reset Timer Button
    Button(onClick = { resetTimer() }) {
        Text(text = "Reset")
    }
}

As I stated above, the timer increments by one after resetting to zero. I tried putting a coroutine inside the "resetTimer" function and putting a delay of thirty milliseconds between the two variables like this
fun resetTimer() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        isTimerRunning = false
        delay(30)
        time = 0
    }
}

but the problem still persists.

resetTimer stops the timer by setting isTimerRunning = false. The timer mostly just waits at delay(1000), so when you set isTimerRunning = false it will probably be doing just that in the moment. After the dealy is finished timer is incremented by one (the unwanted behavior you observed) and only then tests in the while loop if isTimerRunning is still true. It isn't, so the loop is ended and the coroutine finshes - but the timer is already 1, not 0.
You could fix that by changing your coroutine to this:
delay(1000)
while (isTimerRunning) {
    time += 1
    delay(1000)
}

Now the next thing that happens when delay is done is to verify if isTimerRunning is true, not incrementing the timer.

While this will work most of the time, this actually is a race condition since you have two separate threads involved that access the same, mutable state: It could happen that the coroutine has already checked that isTimerRunning is true, then resetTimer sets isTimerRunning = false and time to 0, and then the coroutine sets time += 1, resulting in the reset timer being 1 again.
Even worse, the last statement is actually two different statements:
time = time + 1

The first is reading time and incrementing it by 1, the second is setting the result of that calculation to time. Now imagine if in between these two the other thread running resetTimer resets time to 0. Let's assume time was 10 before, and let the two threads involved be named Main and IO, then the following happens:

The IO thread reads time and increments it by one, making it 11. That is only the result of the calculation and not yet written back to the time variable.
The Main thread sets time to 0
The IO thread writes the result of the calculation back to time which is now 11.

The timer is stopped now, but instead of being reset to 0 it will be 11.
This is a common problem in a multithreading environment when accessing Shared mutable state. In your specific case it can easily be remedied by letting the coroutine run in the UI thread as well, just don't use Dispatchers.IO. That will guarantee that only one block of code can be run at a time and nothing can interfere while your coroutine is not currently waiting for delay.
Actually, you shouldn't use CoroutineScope in the first place because it creates an unmanaged, dangling coroutine scope that cannot be cancelled. When in composable code you can retrieve a scope by calling rememberCoroutineScope(), in the view model you should use viewModelScope.

One problem using the apporach of actively increasing the time counter is that your clock will slowly drift from the real time that elapsed because you do not just increase the counter exactly every 1000 milliseconds, it will always be a bit more. See the first two points I made in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78742092/6216216 for a thorough explanation why that is.
If you do not need your stop watch to be accurate then that won't be a problem, otherwise you will need to change your approach by only saving the time when the stop watch was started, as also explained (and elaborated) in the linked answer above.

Thanks, I just moved the delay to the bottom of the coroutine and it appears to work for now. I still don't understand the thing you said in the other question about subtracting the elapsed time from the system time. How do I get the elapsed time?

Instead of starting a coroutine when you start the stop watch you simply save the current time in a variable. Let's say the time is 11:22:33:. Then, every second, you update your UI with the then-current time and subtract the start time from it. After the first second it is 11:22:34, so you calculate 11:22:34 - 11:22:33 = 00:00:01. After another second it is 11:22:35 which results in 00:00:02 and so on. It doesn't matter how often you update your UI (every second, every millisecond, every hour), the stop watch will always be accurate.

You can even save the start time in a database, close the app and when the app is started again you can resume displaying the elapsed time. It is still accurate because you don't actively count the elapsed seconds, you just calculate the elapsed time. You can find the code needed to retrieve the current time and calculate the elapsed time in my answer to your previous question.

Okay save LocalTime.now into a variable and subtract the start time from it. What is the start time and how do I save it into a variable?

As already mentioned the code for that is in my answer to your previous question. Here is the link again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78742092/6216216

where do I put "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime" dependency. In the project or module file? I tried both and it says "unresolved reference"

As all dependencies it belongs in the module level gradle file. If you have further questions feel free to ask them as a new question, the comments section is only there to discuss the current question/answer (i.e. your resetTimer issue). Make sure to search Stack Overflow first before asking, because adding dependencies to gradle files is a very common task, there will most likely already be a question covering this.

I solved this problem by check isTimerRunning variable inside while loop of startTimer function before increment value of time.
As I understand it the coroutine scope cannot check whether isTimerRunning is false if it's running delay method that in while loop so we need to check it inside too.
// Start Timer Function
fun startTimer() {
    isTimerRunning = true
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        while (isTimerRunning) {
            delay(1000)
            if(isTimerRunning) time += 1
        }
    }
}

Thanks for report Leviathan.

This won't work though if there would also be another function just pausing the timer (by also setting isTimerRunning = false) without resetting it.

Actually you are right. I have another idea what if we check the isTimerRunning before incerement the time value?
